# deserialize json with an array of items

Tags: json, vb.net

There is a web service that returns some json like this:

```
{
    "ContainerCount": 36,
    "ContainerUnits": "",
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|52484481|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Google UK Ltd, 1 St. Giles High Street, London, WC2H...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|52484493|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Google UK Ltd, Colonnade Walk, 123 Buckingham Palace Road, London, SW1W...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|28329353|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Google UK Ltd, Belgrave House, 76 Buckingham Palace Road, London, SW1W...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|52844784|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Google UK Ltd, 7 Pancras Square, London, N1C...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|50573331|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Google, Peter House, Oxford Street, Manchester, M1...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|12492688|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Johnny Goggles, 32 North John Street, Liverpool, L2...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        },
        {
            "Id": "GBR|PR|12682667|0|0|0",
            "Text": "Jonny Goggles, 274 Stanley Road, Bootle, L20...",
            "Highlight": "",
            "Cursor": 0,
            "Description": "",
            "Next": "Retrieve"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to deserialize this JSON.

The ultimate goal is to display the text of an element in a combobox, an then do further queries with the 'ID' of the element selected by the combo box.

Comment: Which deserializer are you wanting to use?  have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks for putting the code into a block. json.net. I'm unsure how to organise the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create these classes

```
    public class Container
    {
        public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserialize like this:

```
    var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);
```

Get the items:

```
    container.Items
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I would up-vote, but I require 15 reputation to do so, and I'm a newbie.